# Setting a query to a recordset

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to set a recordset that keeps giving me the error message - "Runtime Error 3061 Too few parameters. Expected 1". 
The query checks to see what value is in a combo box and then returns two fields. This is the VBA code I tried -

```
Dim db As Database
Dim rst As Recordset2
Dim field As field

Dim n As Integer
Dim Qno As Integer
Dim sqlstr As String

Set db = DBEngine(0)(0)
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("Get_Questions", dbOpenDynaset)
```

This is the SQL behind the Get_Questions Query -

```
SELECT Question_Lt.Qnumber, Question_Lt.Questions, Question_Lt.Freq
FROM Question_Lt
WHERE (((Question_Lt.ClientCd)=[Forms]![TestForm]![CmClient]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use your query as a `QueryDef` object, supply the parameter value, and then use its `OpenRecordset` method to populate your recordset.

```vb
'Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("Get_Questions", dbOpenDynaset)
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("Get_Questions")
qdf.Parameters(0).Value = [Forms]![TestForm]![CmClient]
Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenDynaset)
```

Answer (score 0):

i ve to few reputation points to comment your question. But what ist the SQL Statement exactly. It seems to me that your ' ' are not set but i don' t know

Im Just guessing: Sql Script for Get_Questions  should be something like that. I don' t know the parameter "Get_Questions" is it a query-name?

```
sqlStr =
   "SELECT...
    FROM Question_LT
    WHERE Client.Cd = " & [Forms]![TestForm]![CmClient]
```

Comment: this is the SQL view of the Query I created. I didnt add the SQL statement to VBA because I was trying to use the Query name instead. HansUp seems to have answered the question below. Thanks chroni